# Associate Exploratory Test Cases with Test Plan

Tags: testing, microsoft-test-manager, test-plan

The following question is regarding Microsofts Test Manger, which is included with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Premium and higher.

I have a hierarchic structure of *test plans*.

*Example*:

[image]

When I want to create a new *test case* I usually do an *exploratory test* and then create a new *test case* from it by clicking on *Create test case*:

[image]

This has the benefit, that my performed steps during the test are automatically documented. My problem here is that I can not select to which *test plan* I would like to add my new *test case*. 
After saving the new *test case*, it will be added to the root *test plan*, which in this case ist *WEB Test*. Then I have to move the *test case* manually into the appropriate sub *test plan*. This kind of workflow seems more like a workaround instead of a workflow.

My question therefore is, how to associate a new *test case*, which is created by an *exploratory test*, with a specific *test plan*?

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that when I use a requirements-based test suite, that right-clicking the suite will show an "Explore requirement" menu item. Clicking it starts up exploratory testing. I haven't tried this yet, but it's possible that any test case created during that testing will be associated with the requirement, and possibly even with the suite.